# HTML, Place divs near each other

Tags: html, css, block

I have a problem in my html code. I have "Title" , "Firstname" and "Surname" and I need an input box bellow them to be completed by users. these input boxes are defined in my form generator as fields (e.g. [en_title])
Now when I write down the html code to show the output, the blocks are placed under each other. I want to place them near each other and when I use float in my div style, they place near each other BUT the input boxes shrink, while in first case the input boxes don't shrink.
Please give me a solution for this issue that the blocks placed near each other and the boxes don't shrink. thanks

```
<div>
  Title <br />
  [en_title]
</div>
<div>
  Firstname <br />
  [en_fname]
</div>
<div>
  Surname <br />
  [en_sname]
</div>
```

Comment: If you only have 3 elements, use `float: left; width: 33.333%`. If there are any paddings or borders involved add `box-sizing: border-box`

Comment: fixed widths is probably what you need. Would have been better if you'd shown your existing CSS though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have 3 div that you want to place near each other horizontally.
the width of the div which contain all these div is 100%.
So each div have a 100/3 % width.
It works as Bootstrap for example.

You can do that like this

**Run the snippet**

```css
.your-block {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="your-block">
    <label for="title">Title </label> <br />
    <input id="title" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="your-block">
    <label for="firstname">firstname </label> <br />
    <input id="firstname" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="your-block">
    <label for="surname">surname </label> <br />
    <input id="surname" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: but @shp if you change padding of your div, you have to reduce width.
Try to use tools like bootstrap for example which can easily help you

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float`

```css
div{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
Title <br />
<input type="text"/>
</div>
<div>
Firstname <br />
<input type="text"/>
</div>
<div>
Surname <br />
<input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use width and also use `position:absolute` so that you can move your control anywhere with `margin-left:10px` or `margin-top:10px` whatever in your case. Also it would be helpful if you share your css code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution: 
Don't use divitis for this, use labels and input fields:

HTML:

```
<form>
  <label> Name <input type="text"> </label>
  <label> Email <input type="email"> </label>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form{display: flex}
```

This way you have semantic HTML and achieve the look you want. 
A good overview on what can be done with flexbox is on css-tricks: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/